# How to retrieve the image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one url , which returns an image tag.Now i need to call this url using javascript , and embed this return  under a div tag.
I was trying $.get(), but "data" is returning some text.How to retrieve the image in javascript.
note: pls provide sln with javascript/jquery.

Edit: data returns GIF40 or soem this kind of arbitary value..

Comment: just `GIF40`??? no tags or whatsoever?...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.ajax({
   method: 'get',
   url: 'image.php',
   success: function(data){
      $('#divId').append($(data).find('img')); 
  }

})
```

Comment: i tried  $.get('myurl', function(data) {
                //$('.result').html(data);
            $('#myid').append($(data).find('IMG'));; ..but it didnt work

Comment: its returning image name..not image.

Comment: ahh, I'm guessing it's the path of the src of the img tag thats causing you the problem.... maybe because it's not pointing to a full path...

Comment: its a full path..id i paste myurl in browser, it retruns an image

Comment: can you please put in your question above the output of `'myurl'` in your `$.get()`